# How to prevent re-triggering methods from continuous data?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this app that is using the iBeacon stuff. 
Building upon AirLocate, I'm listing the beacons in my neighborhood.

This is done in a UITableView as follows:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    self.rangedRegions[region] = beacons;
    [self.beacons removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableArray *allBeacons = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray *regionResult in [self.rangedRegions allValues])
    {
        [allBeacons addObjectsFromArray:regionResult];
    }

    for (NSNumber *range in @[@(CLProximityUnknown), @(CLProximityImmediate), @(CLProximityNear), @(CLProximityFar)])
    {
        NSArray *proximityBeacons = [allBeacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximity = %d", [range intValue]]];
        if([proximityBeacons count])
        {
            self.beacons[range] = proximityBeacons;
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

from there on,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called.

Here I call a method, that queries an online database for a value, specific to a cell.

The problem is, that the Location Manager is sending virtually continuous updates, forcing me to repeatedly send requests to the database for information that is not changing after the first query. After which I have to update the UI again.

What is the best approach to avoid this redundant query?

I hope this makes sense

thanks in advance

S

---

Here are the tableView delegates :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    myCell *cell = [tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    NSNumber *sectionKey = [self.beacons allKeys][indexPath.section];
    CLBeacon *beacon = self.beacons[sectionKey][indexPath.row];

    User * myBuddy = [self retrieveDataFromUserwithMajor:[beacon.major shortValue] andMinor:[beacon.minor shortValue]];
    NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myplace.com/%@.png", myBuddy.userID];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    cell.userSelfie.image=image;
    cell.userName.text=myBuddy.userName;
    cell.userSetting2.text=myBuddy.userSetting2;
    cell.userSetting3.text=myBuddy.userSetting3;
     }


    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.beacons.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *sectionValues = [self.beacons allValues];
    return [sectionValues[section] count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "irrelevant logic" is actually relevant because chances are it changes your table's data source array and knowing the changes to your data source array could have helped in formulating an answer...

But generally speaking, if `didRangeBeacons` is in fact where you are changing your data source, what you can do is (1) save a copy of your current data array at the top of the `didRangeBeacons` method, (2) change your data array using the "logic," then (3) only reload the data if the data source array has changed.

Edit: From your code it looks like self.beacons is your table's data source, so I've updated the code accordingly.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    // Save a copy of the original self.beacons dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *originalDataSource = [self.beacons copy];

    self.rangedRegions[region] = beacons;
    [self.beacons removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableArray *allBeacons = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray *regionResult in [self.rangedRegions allValues])
    {
        [allBeacons addObjectsFromArray:regionResult];
    }

    for (NSNumber *range in @[@(CLProximityUnknown), @(CLProximityImmediate), @(CLProximityNear), @(CLProximityFar)])
    {
        NSArray *proximityBeacons = [allBeacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximity = %d", [range intValue]]];
        if([proximityBeacons count])
        {
            self.beacons[range] = proximityBeacons;
        }
    }

    // If the original dictionary has changed, reload the data
    if (![originalDataSource isEqualToDictionary:self.beacons] {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Lyndsey! Since I'm not sure how to get to the 
self.tableDataSourceArray
I included the 'irrelevant logic' into the question......potentially making a fool out of myself.

Comment: @Sjakelien Is self.beacons a dictionary or an array?

Comment: @Sjakelien OK, updated. I'm assuming self.beacons is your table's data source, but I can't be sure unless I see your table view delegate methods...

Comment: Bear with me, I'm dealing with several devices interacting with each other while sharing the same code. My initial findings are, that 
[self.tableView reloadData];
is still being called continuously. Apparently, the dictionary is changing.

Comment: @Sjakelien Is self.beacons your data source? Meaning is that the data that populates your table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69776/discussion-between-sjakelien-and-lyndsey-scott).